# How to Display PDF File with in the same App in phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, pdf-viewer

how to show Pdf file with in the same phonegap app. i tried Inappbrowser,Mupdf,PDFJS all are displaying PDF using other pdf viewer.i would like to open the pdf file with in the same app.Can anyone help me out.Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this is the plugin you're looking for? Look at the bottom of the Documentation, there are screenshots: https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer

Answer (score 5):

for cordova, sachinM's answer is perfect - but with an extensions
Use uriEncodeComponent(link) and https://docs.google.com/viewer?url= link

Doc, Excel, Powerpoint and pdf all supported.

Use the cordova in app browser.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
        }

            $("body").on("click",function(e){
           var clicked = $(e.target);
         if(clicked.is('a, a *'))
       {
             clicked = clicked.closest("a");
             var link = clicked.attr("href");
            if(link.indexOf("https://") !== -1)
           {
               if(true) //use to be able to determine browser from app
                 {
                    link = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" +  encodeURIComponent(link) + "&embedded=true";
             }

                 window.open(link, "_blank", "location=no,toolbar=no,hardwareback=yes");
                return false;
            }
    }
    });
```

Comment: This works. Are you able to listen for events with this method? 'loadstart', 'loadstop' ...etc

Answer (score 3):

(Excuse my poor English) I don't know what you mean "in the same app", because `inappbrowser`, `Mupdf` and `pdf.js` can all do that.

In Android platform, most popular solution is send `intent` and open via other pdf viewers because users can choose there favorite(you can try [File Opener 2](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2)). If you don't like that, you can build an Activity for displaying pdf in your app, just like [MuPDF Viewer](https://github.com/evandenberg/mupdf-viewer). If you want open pdf file in Cordova/Phonegap webview, you need mozilla's [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/), that's a pure-js lib for rendering pdf file on HTML5 canvas, but it pretty slower than using native solution (even you build with [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/)), so I dont suggest that.

It's much easier in iOS platforms. iOS's `UIWebView` can open pdf files natively, so all you need is using [inAppBrowser Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser). If you want more features, there're many plugins (like [Cordova PDFReader IOS](https://github.com/etabard/Cordova-PDFReader-IOS)) you can choose.

Hope that helps with you.

Comment: Thanks i got it,I can open PDF File With in the app.but i have to show with a div.

Comment: @Fomahaut I've tried PDF.js but from what I understand it needs the page to be served from a web server. Are you sure this works with a Cordova mobile app?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Docs Viewer plugin for jQuery to display pdf document in div.
Click [here](http://www.jawish.org/blog/archives/394-Google-Docs-Viewer-plugin-for-jQuery.html)