# Display pdf file using cordova javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, pdf-viewer

How can I show a PDF file in Cordova ? I am using the whitelist plugin to display a PDF file but I dont know the procedure (I can't use any  jQuery code). At the page load time Pdf is shown that I want... is that whitelist  plugin is correct for this purpose

Comment: You can't just load it into a webview?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935051/open-pdf-in-cordova-app-android/41094316